# How to make the change event work, in select, after change ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular

I use Angular2, and have html code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
            <select class="form-control"
                    id="country"
                    [(ngModel)]="testSelectModel"
                    (change)="testSelectChange($event)">
                <option *ngFor="let item of textCollection"
                        [value]="item.id">
                    {{item.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="testSelectModel"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also have a collection of textCollection, objects which - {
                name: 'foo',
                id: 1
            }...
I enter (id) in input 1, and wanted see selected item in tag select.
Yes, all is well, the item has changed, but the event "testSelectChange" - is not invoked..

### [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5V50NvkSs3a0J3sD8FAA?p=preview)

Somebody faced such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the input, `testSelectChange()` won't get called, even though the `select` DOM element and the `input` DOM element are both bound to the same component property, `testSelectModel`.  Angular will only call `testSelectChanges()` if there is a change to one of `select`'s DOM properties, and this doesn't happen when you change the `input` value.

I suggest breaking up the event and data binding – use `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` – for each binding:

```ts
<select [ngModel]="testSelectModel" 
        (ngModelChange)="testSelectChange($event)">
...
<input [ngModel]="testSelectModel"
       (ngModelChange)="testInputChange($event)">
```

Note that `$event` will be set to the current value of the select or input.

Then manually call the the select change event handler from `testInputChange()`:

```ts
testSelectChange(newValue) {
    console.log('testSelectChange', newValue);
    this.testSelectModel = newValue;
    this.resultWorkModel = newValue;
}
testInputChange(newValue) {
  console.log('testInputChange', newValue)
  this.testSelectModel = newValue;
  this.testSelectChange(newValue);  // manually trigger other event handler
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HP7C6zX41MNpDn4SImGE?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The event for handle changes in the model is `ngModelChange`, your code should be like this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
            <select class="form-control"
                    id="country"
                    [(ngModel)]="testSelectModel"
                    (ngModelChange)="testSelectChange($event)">
                <option *ngFor="let item of textCollection"
                        [value]="item.id">
                    {{item.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="testSelectModel"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is a example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/omo7H3J5v692TchZFFlR?p=preview) Enjoy.

Comment: your solution does not work, I've added an example on plnkr.co

Answer (score 0):

Besides what the other commenters have said, you might also need to write your handler in a Future, because the changes to testSelectModel might not have taken effect before testSelectChange($event) has happened.

This was the case in Angular1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
[Plunker Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/X1Iy16nge9lbSPl6D752?p=preview)

html:

```
    <select class="form-control" #type [(ngModel)]="testSelectModel" (change)='testSelectChange(type.value)'>
      <option *ngFor="#item of textCollection" [value]="item.id">
        {{item.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

class:

```
testSelectChange(val: string) {
  console.log('I call', val);
  this.resultWorkModel = this.textCollection.find((obj) => obj.id == val).name;
```

}

Comment: your solution does not work, I've added an example on plnkr.co

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by it didnt work... here is  plnkr code for my solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/X1Iy16nge9lbSPl6D752?p=preview